# sub that returns a matched regex group

Tags: regex, perl

I am parsing lines of the form

```
12:34 SomeEvent: 0 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

I have a handler sub that just gets a line and uses `given/when` to pass it to a more specific handler sub based on regex matches—for example, the line above would be passed to the `_someevent` sub.

In these specific handler subs I would like to extract the `0` part of the line, which is like an ID.

I have written the following sub for this purpose:

```
sub _getid ($) { $_[0] =~ /\d+:\d+ \w+: (\d+)/ }
```

This sub seems to work when when used like this:

```
say _getid("12:34 SomeEvent: 0 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\n");
```

But when I assign the result to a variable:

```
my $id = _getid("12:34 SomeEvent: 0 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\n");
say "ID = $id";
```

it just always turns into `1`. I believe this has to do with the fact that the `=~` regex match actually returns a list or something and I am assigning it to a scalar…?

I came up with the following instead:

```
sub _getid ($) {
    $_[0] =~ /\d+:\d+ \w+: (\d+)/;
    $1; # or return $1;
}
```

But there must be a better, elegant way to tackle the problem.

Comment: [Perl prototypes](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub#Prototypes) likely do not do what you think they do, and you should probably not use them.

Comment: The regex you say you are using does not match the sample string you provide. There is a missing colon in the regex.

Comment: @TLP indeed, thanks for the heads-up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One elegant (?) way to make sure the subroutine always returns a scalar is to use a subscript on the list returned by the regex match:

```perl
sub _getid {
    ($_[0] =~ /\d+:\d+ \w+: (\d+)/)[0];    # subscript makes parenthesis return
                                           # 1st element of list
}
```

Of course, this is all very code "golfy". I would probably write this subroutine more explicitly, making the code actually readable for other people:

```
sub _getid {
    my $str = shift;
    my ($return) = $str =~ /\d+:\d+ \w+ (\d+)/;
    return $return;
}
```

Some notes on your code.

- Be aware than when you use `$_[0]` you can inadvertently alter the argument, because you are accessing it directly. A safer option is to copy the content to a new, lexically scoped variable, like in my example above.

Consider for example `sub foo { $_[0]++ }`. If you run `my $foo = 0; foo($foo); print $foo;` this will print `1`, showing that `$foo` was altered by the subroutine. If you try `foo(2)` you will also get the rather strange error `Modification of a read-only value attempted`.

- You should probably not use prototypes for your subroutines. They have a special use in Perl, and it is not what most people think. I.e. you should do `sub foo { ... }` and not `sub foo ($) { ... }`. Documentation [here](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub#Prototypes)

Answer (score 3):

You're being burnt by context. From [perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop) (specifically, the section on [Regexp Quote-Like Operators](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators)):

> */PATTERN/msixpodualngc*
>
> Searches a string for a pattern match, and in scalar context returns
> true if it succeeds, false if it fails.

And later:

> **Matching in list context**
>
> If the /g option is not used, m// in list context returns a list
> consisting of the subexpressions matched by the parentheses in the
> pattern, that is, ($1, $2, $3...) (Note that here $1 etc. are also
> set). When there are no parentheses in the pattern, the return value
> is the list (1) for success. With or without parentheses, an empty
> list is returned upon failure.

Turning to your code.

> ```
> say _getid("12:34 SomeEvent: 0 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\n");
> ```

`say()` imposes list context on its arguments, so you get a list of the captures. You only have one capture, so the list has one element (your ID) and that's what gets printed.

> ```
> my $id = _getid("12:34 SomeEvent: 0 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\n");
> ```

Assigning to a scale variable is a pretty obvious example of scalar context. So you get the behaviour described in the first extract from the docs. The "1" your seeing is the true value.

[**Update:** My explanation of the problem (all the stuff above this point) is good. But my suggested fix (the stuff below this point) isn't as useful as I originally thought. The other answers form TLP and ikegami both include far better solutions.]

To fix this, you need to impose list context on your subroutine call. The easiest way to do that is to replace your scalar assignment with a list assignment - by putting parentheses around the variable.

```
my ($id) = _getid("12:34 SomeEvent: 0 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\n");
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have mentioned I thought of this solution too. However, it seems wrong that `_getid` returns a list in the first place. Is there a way to tweak `_getid` instead in such a way that it returns the first matched group as a scalar?

Comment: Re "*However, it seems wrong that `_getid` returns a list in the first place.*", Indeed, being forced to call `_getid` in list context is not exactly nice.

Answer (score 2):

You have this:

```perl
sub _getid ($) {
    $_[0] =~ /\d+:\d+ \w+ (\d+)/;
    $1; # or return $1;
}
```

The above fails poorly if the string doesn't match (returning some "random" string). The following also work, but fail a lot more safely:

```perl
# Match in scalar context returns whether the match succeeded or not.
# Returns $1, or undef if no match.
sub _getid { $_[0] =~ /\d+:\d+ \w+ (\d+)/ ? $1 : undef }
```

```perl
# Match in list context returns captures.
# Using a slice, this returns $1, or undef if no match.
sub _getid { ( $_[0] =~ /\d+:\d+ \w+ (\d+)/ )[0] }
```

Answer (score -2):

The code works as it was *designed* to work and not what OP was expecting.

First mistake is hidden in match pattern as it does not account for `:` after *SomeEvent*.

Result of match in scalar context will indicate if there was match or not -- consider it as bool variable.

If modifier `/g` would be used and several matches occur in the string then result of match will be a count of matches.

If on the left side of the match OP would have a list (an array) variable then he would fill the array with matched groups, but original code does not utilize this approach.

What OP should do is demonstrated in modified version of `_getid()` subroutine.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $str = "12:34 SomeEvent: 0 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\n";
my $var;

$var = $str =~ /\d+:\d+ \w+ (\d+)/;
say "-[$var]-";

$var = $str =~ /\d+:\d+ \w+: (\d+)/;
say "-[$var]-";

my $id = _getid($str);
say '_getid returned: ' . $id;

sub _getid {
    my $str = shift;
    
    return $1 if $str =~ /\d+:\d+ \w+: (\d+)/;
    
    return undef;
}
```

Output

```
-[]-
-[1]-
_getid returned: 0
```

Documentation: [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre)

Comment: `return undef` is usually better written as just `return`.